# Error JavaScrit code trying to live search a paginated table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to find one particular name and position, for someone listed in a paginated table with a webpage search bar. The code below is very simple league system. The data is ordered by profit desc. The position is calculated using row number and is then paginated.

So for example Page 1 will have the first 31 records, numbered 1-31, with the highest profit at position 1 next 2 and so on. Page 1 is labelled league 1. The next 31 records become league 2 again with the top profit in league 2 becoming position 1 ect.

Everything works fine apart from my search bar. What I am trying to do is enter a name in the search bar to find what league that person is in and what their position is. Ideally, the search result should show the page which the person is listed and somehow highlight that person. At the moment I am stuck on finding the name. The JavaScript at the bottom of the code, I thought should find the name and hide the rest but it does not. It works fine when using it on a basic hand coded html table. I would be grateful for any thoughts in pointing me in the right direction.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Sales League</title>
</head>

<body>

      <?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","salesleague");

     $rpp = 31;

        isset($_GET['page']) ? $page = $_GET['page'] : $page = 1;
        if($page > 1){
           $start = ($page * $rpp) - $rpp;
        }else{
            $start = 0;
        }
   $resultSet = $con->query("SELECT id from salesleague_march");
   $numRows = $resultSet->num_rows;

    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0){
            $rowNumber=0;}


   $totalPages = $numRows / $rpp;

   $resultSet = $con->query("SELECT * FROM salesleague_march ORDER by Profit desc LIMIT $start, $rpp");
    echo "<h1>Sales League $page  </h1>" ;
   echo "<table id='tabl1' border 1px >
   <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Branch</th>  
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>Profit</th>
        </tr>";

    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){

        $rowNumber++;
        $name = $rows['Name'];
        $branch = $rows['Branch'];
        $units = $rows['Units'];
        $profit = number_format($rows['Profit']);


    echo "<tr><td>$rowNumber</td><td>$name</td><td>$branch</td><td>$units</td><td>£ $profit</td></tr>";    
    }
    echo "</table><p />";

    for($x = 1; $x <= $totalPages + 1; $x++){
        echo "<a href='?page=$x'>$x</a>  ";
     }

?> 


    <input type="text" id="Namesearch" placeholder="Salesperson Search"></input>

    <script>
    $("#Namesearch") .on("keyup", function()
    {
      var value=$(this) .val(); 
      $ ("table tr") .each(function(records)
      {
        if(records !==0)
        {
         var id=$ (this) .find ("td:first") .text(); 
            if(id.indexOf(value)!==0 && id.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLocaleLowerCase())<0)
            {
             $ (this) .hide();   
            }
            else
            {
             $(this) .show ();
            }
        }

      });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'd have execute a new query using the search string

Comment: If `(Profit)` is not a key (i.e. not unique) that pagination will be unstable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment’s guys, I am relatively new to coding so my knowledge is a little sparse, so any comments will help. If I use a new query using the search string (Phaelax z) surely that would just query the database table not the table on the webpage? Also, profit is a field in the table, is that what you mean by key, or do you mean primary key? (The Impaler). Thanks for your interest and help.